# How to format the date of jquery UI datepicker to 2013-05-26 12:41:07 format?

Tags: jquery-ui, date, datetime, format, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using the jquery UI datepicker, I want to format the date value picked to a date and time in the format example `2013-05-26 12:41:07` which is the MySQL datetime value.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only use the datepicker or with a timepicker plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They said that datepicker is used only for pick the date, you should consider using some timepicker plugin like http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

And make it suit your needs.